# networkx edge color is always black, color attribute is ignored

Tags: python, graph, networkx, edges

I have some analysis rules i want to represent, and i want the edges that come in and out of certain nodes to have the same colour. I approached it with different ways but none of them worked. For example:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
color_map = []
color_iter = 0
edge_colors_iter = ["#4e79a9", "#59a14f", "#9c755f", "#f28e2b", "#edc948", "#bab0ac", "#e15759", "#b07aa1",
                    "#76b7b2", "#ff9da7"]

for index, row in rules.iterrows():

    edges_to_add = []
    color_of_rule = edge_colors_iter[color_iter]


    #left_side_items and right_side_items are essentially lists for in and out edges 
    #of the certain node i need with the same color
    # ...

    for item in left_side_items:
        edges_to_add.append((str(item), "R"+str(rule_id)))

    for item in right_side_items:
        edges_to_add.append(("R"+str(rule_id), str(item)))

    G.add_edges_from(edges_to_add, color=color_of_rule)

    color_iter += 1

for node in G:

    if str(node).startswith("R"):
        color_map.append('#f9dc4c')

    else:
        color_map.append('#339e34')

nx.draw_circular(G, node_color=color_map, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

I get the correct graph but the colors are always black, for example
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently nx.draw_circular does not consider the colors attribute and must be explicitly given.

```
for item in left_side_items:
    G.add_edge(str(item), "R"+str(rule_id), color=color_of_rule)

for item in right_side_items:
    G.add_edge("R"+str(rule_id), str(item), color=color_of_rule)

color_iter += 1
```

After adding the colors to each edge you can get them in a list that will be passed to the draw_circular.

```
edges = G.edges()
colors = [G[u][v]['color'] for u, v in edges]

nx.draw_circular(G, edge_color=colors, node_size=final_node_sizes, node_color=color_map, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the keyword argument `edge_color` where you specify the desired colors.
Example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.complete_graph(n=6)

color_map = []
for u, v in G.edges():
    if u % 2 == 0 and v % 2 == 0:
        color_map.append('#f9dc4c')
    else:
        color_map.append('#339e34')

nx.draw_circular(G, edge_color=color_map, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]